# почему ответ выдает 0?в чем ошибка

Tags: pascal

Program Temperature;

```
var 
  T: array[1..12] of integer;
  I: integer;
  S: real;
begin
  I:=1;
  while I <= 12 do
  begin
    readln(T[I]);
    I := I + 1;
  end;
  S := 0;
  while I <= 12 do
  begin 
    S := S + T[I];
    S := S / 12;
  end;
  writeln(S);
end.
```

Comment: `S := S / 12;` может вне цикла должно быть?

Comment: Не решение проблемы, но: если это программа для расчета средней температуры за год, то нужно сначала сложить все числа, а только потом делить на 12 вне цикла.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что к моменту

```
S := 0;
while I <= 12 do
```

`I` уже равно `13`. Обнулите эту переменную перед вторым циклом.

```
S := 0;
I := 0;
while I <= 12 do
begin 
  S := S + T[I];
  I := I + 1;
end;
S := S / 12;
```

Comment: а в паскале нет ошибки типа array index out of range или типа того?

Comment: _Обнулите эту переменную перед вторым циклом._ - и добавить счетчик тоже надо.

Comment: @Эникейщик Есть (если включена опция компилятора "Range checking"). Но код просто не заходит во второй `while`.

Comment: А, ну точно. Не сообразил.